# Thread1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address = 0X48) when button is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

```
var buttonTapPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()


override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        do{
            let correctSoundUrl: URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "buttonTap", ofType: "wav")!)
            self.buttonTapPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: correctSoundUrl)
            self.buttonTapPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        }
        catch{}
    }
}


@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {

      self.buttonTapPlayer.play()
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: sender)

}
```

I have the above code in my swift project. My project crashes the very first time I run the project in simulator at `self.buttonTapPlayer.play()`
with the following error:

> Thread1:EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address = 0X48)

However, when I re-run it, everything is fine. How do I resolve this?

Comment: i just tested your code.. you have problem setting up segue identifier...

Comment: @Coder221 Is the issue still there if you don't dispatch those three lines in `viewDidLoad` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it. You've build your `buttonTapPlayer` in a background thread and you try to call it from the main thread (to `IBAction` method). The compiler crashed to `play()` because your player is not yet ready.

To avoid this, you could build your player inside:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   // build your stuff to the main thread
}
```

or simply remove  `DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {}`

Comment: Appreciate the explanation , I built it in DispatchQueue.main.async{}, it works fine.